# Calculate area covered by pixels in several rasters

Tags: r, raster

I've a list of 96 categorical rasters (each with an associated variable i.e. rcp, period and month) with values ranging from 1-16 and I would like to calculate the area covered by each of those categories in each raster and return NA if the category doesn't exist in a raster.

This is the function I have created for now

```
a <- function(x){
rs <- x #categorical raster
b <- getValues(area(x, weights=FALSE))
b <- aggregate(b, by=list(getValues(x)), sum, na.rm=T)
b <- as.data.frame(b)
names(b) <- c("CLASS","AREA")
return(b)
}
```

The problem with this is that it returns a data frame with the existing raster values only and without the missing values. See below:

```
  CLASS       AREA
1     1 145084.052
2     5  39425.336
3     6  37912.591
4    10  10089.541
5    11   3150.571
6    15   1451.912
7    16   4289.296
```

How can I return a data frame with all the categories (1-16)? and combine all outputs into one? The column names should be rcp, period and month.

Here is my code for now:

```
mthLs <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
rcpLs <- c("rcp26", "rcp45", "rcp60", "rcp85")
periodLs <- c("2020_2049", "2040_2069")

for(rcp in rcpLs){
  rcpDir <- paste0(iDir, "/", rcp)
     for(period in periodLs){
         for (mth in 1:12) {
          rs <- raster(paste0(iDir, "/", rcp, "/", period, "/cng_", mth, ".tif", sep=""))
          b <- a(rs) #using function above
         }
       im <- cbind(RCP=rep(rcp,times=nrow(b)), PERIOD=rep(period,times=nrow(b)), MONTH=rep(mth,times=nrow(b)), b)

      } 
  write.csv(im, paste(oDir, "/output.csv", sep=""), quote=T, row.names=F)    
}
```

Comment: in aggregate, you should use `length` instead of `sum`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help

```
txt <- 
"CLASS,REA
1,145084.052
5,39425.336
6,37912.591
10,10089.541
11,3150.571
15,1451.912
16,4289.296"

b <- read.csv(textConnection(txt),sep =  ",")

classes <- 1:16

merge(data.frame(CLASS = classes), b, by='CLASS', all.x=T)
```

result:

```
   CLASS        REA
1      1 145084.052
2      2         NA
3      3         NA
4      4         NA
5      5  39425.336
6      6  37912.591
7      7         NA
8      8         NA
9      9         NA
10    10  10089.541
11    11   3150.571
12    12         NA
13    13         NA
14    14         NA
15    15   1451.912
16    16   4289.296
```

Comment: Thanks. The output is from a loop where by each raster has a year and month. How can I merge all this into one data frame?

Comment: I guess if you post all the data, and the expected output, that would help get you a final answer. What have you tried sofar?

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nc=5, nr=5)
set.seed(20171214)
r1 <- setValues(r, sample(16, ncell(r), replace=TRUE))
r2 <- setValues(r, sample(16, ncell(r), replace=TRUE))
r3 <- setValues(r, sample(16, ncell(r), replace=TRUE))
```

If you can make a RasterStack (RasterLayers with same extent and resolution), you can do:

```
s <- stack(r1,r2,r3)
x <- freq(s)

m <- data.frame(value=1:16)
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    y <- x[[i]]
    colnames(y)[2] <- paste0("v", i)
    m <- merge(m, y, all.x=TRUE)
}

m
#   value v1 v2 v3
#1      1  3  2  1
#2      2 NA  3 NA
#3      3  2  2  1
#4      4  1  3  2
#5      5  1 NA  2
#6      6  1  3  3
#7      7 NA  3  4
# ...
```

Or, without the RasterStack, create a list of RasterLayer objects e.g. with

```
# z <- lapply(filenames, raster)
```

But for this example we can do it more manually:

```
z <- list(r1, r2, r3)

m <- data.frame(value=1:16)
for (i in 1:length(z)) {
    y <- freq(z[[i]])  
    colnames(y)[2] <- paste0("v", i)
    m <- merge(m, y, all.x=TRUE)
}
```

Or -- perhaps most straightforward --- with a vector with filenames `ff`

```
m <- data.frame(value=1:16)
for (i in 1:length(ff)) {
    y <- freq(raster(ff[i]))  
    colnames(y)[2] <- paste0("v", i)
    m <- merge(m, y, all.x=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not sure whether I would like to go this route because every raster has an associated variable i.e. `rcpLs <- c("rcp26", "rcp45", "rcp60", "rcp85")` and `periodLs <- c("2020_2049", "2040_2069")`. I would to attach these variables in the final data frame using `im <- cbind(RCP=rep(rcp,times=nrow(b)), PERIOD=rep(period,times=nrow(b)), MONTH=rep(mth,times=nrow(b)), b)`. I expect this to write every raster in a row based on the above fields but its not working. Where I'm I going wrong?